# Strange characters printed out for UDP

Tags: c++, udp, winsock2, udpclient

Hello I have a small issue with my code here. I have a default UDP server program which initialises a character array to a size of 30.

The message is passed from the UDP client program to the UDP server program using the character array. When I try converting it to a string , it keeps priniting out these strange characters. Any advice how to get rid of them?

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <winsock2.h>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <sstream>
  #include <string>
  #include <stack>
  #include <vector>

  using namespace std;
  //function declarations
  void Convert(const string & Infix, string & Postfix);
  bool IsOperand(char ch);
  bool TakesPrecedence(char OperatorA, char OperatorB);

  /*My functions I've added*/
  string Change_me(string);
  string Insert_comma(string);
  bool Check_valid(string);
  double Eval(string[]);
  void Next(string);


  #define BUFSIZE 30
  void ErrorHandling(char *message);

  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
WSADATA wsaData;
SOCKET  hServSock;
char message[BUFSIZE];

int strLen;

SOCKADDR_IN servAddr;
SOCKADDR_IN clntAddr;
int clntAddrSize;

if(argc!=2){
    printf("Usage : %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
}

if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0)
    ErrorHandling("WSAStartup() error!");

hServSock=socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if(hServSock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    ErrorHandling("socket() error!");

memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));
servAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
servAddr.sin_port=htons(atoi(argv[1]));
if(bind(hServSock, (SOCKADDR*) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr))==SOCKET_ERROR)
    ErrorHandling("bind() error");

while(1) {
    string Postfix;
    clntAddrSize=sizeof(clntAddr);
    strLen = recvfrom(hServSock, message, BUFSIZE, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&clntAddr,     &clntAddrSize);
    //need help here how to convert char to the string
    string Infix;// test ="(99*100+200)-10";

    char*result;
    result=message;
    Infix=result;

    printf("Test2 %s\n",message);// gibberish printed
```

Comment: does message end with '\0' ?

Comment: Have you checked the result of `recvfrom` to make sure it actually succeeded?

Comment: Also, are you sure that the message is actually plaintex that may be printed with a printf() statement?  Even if it is non-sense, a little example of what you are getting might help.

Answer (score 1):

If the message isn't null-terminated, %s can't format it. Try

```
printf("Test2 %.*s", strlen, message);
```

provided 'strlen' is non-negative of course. You aren't checking that either.